# Is there a native Japanese word for upgrading a document to a new format?

Tags: words, loanwords, word-requests

I have a document in an old version of a template, and I'm moving the contents into a newer version of the template.  I typically describe this process as "upgrading" the document.

[Jisho](http://jisho.org/search/upgrade) suggests `バージョンアップ`, but I'm hoping to find a native term, something that's not technology-specific but rather describes the more general process of moving content from an old format to a new format, which I assume is an action that would have been defined in Japanese bureaucracy long before the introduction of digital word processing.

Comment: Why do you want specifically a native term? What's wrong with `バージョンアップ`? Just that it's a borrowed word?

Comment: What do you mean by "format"? Does it change appearance or other editorial features?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, yes, I'm looking for a term that describes the process more generally that would encompass both modern and traditional content management systems, including systems that were developed pre-Westernization.

Comment: @broccoliforest, an example would be: in template v1, the author's name appears at the top left of the page, on the same line as a creation date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format, but in template v2, the author's name is at the top right, and the creation date is in "yyyy.mm.dd" format below the author's name.  What would we call the process of copying and reformatting the data from a v1 document into a v2 template?

Comment: where are you going to use this word?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, this came up for me specifically in a programming context: "Write a program to upgrade all the v1 documents in the folder to v2",  which probably could use `バージョンアップ`, but I always try to use a native word over a loanword whenever I'm dealing with a concept that would have existed prior to the introduction of the loanword.

Comment: @sigil Then I'd say 形式を改める or something because it doesn't involve content changes. If you say 更新 or バージョンアップ I think I'm going to look for where the wording has been altered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, [更新{こうしん}](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0) is used to mean *update/upgrade*.

Following l'électeur's remark you might be interested in [改{あらた}める](http://jisho.org/search/aratameru) which is not sino-loanword but a native Japanese word as far as I know.

Comment: Is 「更新」 a native Japanese word?  I thought it was a Sino-loanword.